# Set Proxy for Linux server by bash script failed

Tags: linux, bash, proxy

I use the command below to set proxy in command line and it succeed:

```
export http_proxy="http://proxy.company.com:8080/"
```

But When I use a bash script, below is the content of the script

```
export http_proxy="http://proxy.company.com:8080/"
export https_proxy="http://proxy.company.com:8080/"

sudo yum list
```

And it failed.

Can anyone tell me the difference?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "*it failed*"? Please clarify what you are trying to accomplish with your script.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sudo` doesn't respect current user variables. You must use `sudo -E` to preserve current variables. Or you can set the proxy in `/etc/yum.conf`.